# Selecting String within ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell

How do I select only the string that matched without the if statement running through every "paragraph"? Or how do I select a value from only one input object at a time?

Here is my thought process:

```
# Here I have treated each rule as a "paragraph" and used a delimiter on "next". 
$content = Get-Content C:\firewallrules.txt -Delimiter 'next' 

# For every "paragraph"
$content | ForEach-Object {

    if($_ -Match 'set ips-sensor'){

        "Value Found = " + $valuefound

        # This prints every match I want to print ONLY the line that matched then iterate through the rest of the document
        # Basically, I'm trying to say if($_ -Match 'set ips-sensor') then echo that specific line
        
        $valuefound = $content | Select-String ips-sensor\s+.* | % { $_.Matches.Value }
       
    }
    
    else{
        
        "Value Not Found"
         
        }
    
}
```

My expected output would look something like this:

```
Value Not Found
Value Found = ips-sensor "default"
Value Found = ips-sensor "default"
Value Not Found
Value Not Found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Get-Content C:\firewallrules.txt -Delimiter 'next' | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $match = ($_ | Select-String 'ips-sensor.+').Matches.Value
    if ($match) { "Value found: $match" }
    else        { "Value not found" }
  }
```

Or, more efficiently, with only a [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operation, which reports its results in the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches):

```
Get-Content t.txt -Delimiter 'next' | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -match 'ips-sensor.+') { "Value found: $($Matches[0])" }
  else                          { "Value not found" }
}
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `$content | Select-String ...` should have been `$_ | Select-String ...`, because `$content` is the *array* of *all* paragraphs, not the paragraph at hand, as reflected in the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).
- Also, to avoid matching *twice* there is no need to use *both* `-match` and a [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) call.